# Dropdown with multi-option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I want some modification in following jsfiddle

**https://jsfiddle.net/zqvvuts6/5/**

If in child options user click on other then it shows textbox for search.

In dropdown options as following

```
Swedish Cars (parent)
Volvo (child)
Saab (child)
other ( onclick it should show textbox)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zqvvuts6/40/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as shown below,that is a hidden field is created using "display:none" and when the "others" option in the dropdown is selected the "display:block" property will be used and the search input field will appear

```js
function checkSelected(elem){
if(elem.value=="6"){
  document.getElementById("hiddSearch").style.display="block";
}
 else{
document.getElementById("hiddSearch").style.display="none";
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="filter_sport" multiple="multiple"  name="filter_sport" 
     class="selectpicker" title='Choose a Sport'  data-actions-box="true" class="show-menu-arrow" 
     data-selected-text-format="count>3" 
     data-single-item-selected = "Sport Selected"
     data-all-items-selected="All Sports" 
     ata-multi-item-selected = "Sports Selected" onchange="checkSelected(this)">
       
       
      <option value="11" selected="selected">Cricket</option>
      <option value="15" selected="selected">Football</option>
      <option value="3" selected="selected">Hockey</option>
      <option value="16" selected="selected">MMA</option>
      <option value="6" selected="selected">Others</option>
     </select>
<input style="display:none" id="hiddSearch"/>
```

Comment: I want to apply it on second dropdown, pls visit this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zqvvuts6/5/
Swedish Cars (parent)
Volvo (child)
Saab (child)
other ( onclick it should show textbox)